# Ubuntu 12.04 lts crashed. how to access the files in home folder?

Tags: 12.04, boot, login

I am new with Ubuntu. I had installed 12.04 LTS 64 bit version. I had installed all the important updates it showed. Later on I selected some files manually in the recommended updates section. it was about 13-14mb. by default it showed some 140mb files. So I downloaded and installed it and then restarted my laptop and then the grub came. I selected Ubuntu and then it shows a blank screen. I went to the terminal using F1 key and tried commands like `startx`, then `root startx`and then `sudo startx` but nothing works. I don't know what all I installed exactly. another difference I observed is previously it used to show Ubuntu with Linux 3.0.0-23 now its showing Ubuntu 3.0.0-40 at the grub. Also i have my ubuntu password protected.
What should I do? I have got files inside Ubuntu and do not have its backup. how to recover them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in the grub menu if it shows previous versions of your kernel 3.xx, and run it with the old one, Maybe the new kernel is incompatible with something in your laptop.